# Can't find css selector or xpath for this element

Tags: r, xpath, css-selectors

I'm writing an automation script with  RSelenium  and I need it to open page http://bit. do and click on "Shorten" button. I tried to select element by css and xpath with selector gadget but the suggestions it gave to me weren't useful because with these attempts I got "element not visible"

```
#CSS SELECTOR ATTEMPT
shorten <- remDr$findElement('css selector', '.btn')
shorten$clickElement()

#XPATH ATTEMPT
shorten <- remDr$findElement('xpath', '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "btn", " " ))]')
shorten$clickElement()
```

Also I tried

```
shorten <- remDr$findElement(using ='value', value = 'Shorten')
shorten <- remDr$findElement('css selector', '.btn') 
shorten <- remDr$findElement('css selector', 'input.btn')
shorten <- remDr$findElement('css selector', 'td>.btn')
shorten <- remDr$findElement('css selector', 'td. btn')
```

Answer (score 1):

css:

```
input[value=Shorten]
input[onclick*=shorten]
```

xpath:

```
//input[@value='Shorten']
//input(contains(@onclick, 'shorten'))
```